# Rotation of curve function

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am working on some coding where I require expertise in field of Mathematics. I have a function:

$$F(x) = -0.007x^4 + 1.971x^3 - 190.4x^2 + 8150x - 13024$$

I want to rotate some section of this function (i.e. part of the function where $65 < x < 75$) about a point at $x = 65$ to certain angle lets say $\theta$.
Rotating the function at $x= 65$ is important.

Comment: This may not even be a function after the rotation.

Comment: rotating is around a point,  and you only give the x coordinate of the point you rotate around

Answer (score 0):

What you want is quite complicated.

Maybe easiest is to plot your new curve:

- Transform the whole curve into  a parameter curve first so instead if $y = f(x) $ use

$ y = f(t)$ and $x = g(t) $ instead, (in your case $g(t) $ is just $t$ )

- Then to rotate around  point $A(A_x,A_y)$ by  angle $\varphi$ you get:

$x_r = A_x + (g(t) - A_x) \cos(\varphi)  - (f(t) - A_y) \sin(\varphi) $

$y_r = A_y + (g(t) - A_x) \sin(\varphi)  + (f(t) - A_y) \cos(\varphi) $

- Connect the consecutive points $(x_r , y_r)$

GOOD LUCK